# MSSQL работа в транзакциях TRUNCATE. Как это работает?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В MSSQL по моим экспериментам, можно использовать TRUNCATE в транзакциях, но при этом по документации нету упоминания как это работает и в чем разница между DELETE. Я знаю, что TRUNCATE заносит в журнал транзакций только информацию об количестве удаленных строк, но как он тогда восстанавливает данные при ROLLBACK? Был бы благодарен любой проверенной информации.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522931/truncate-table-within-transaction первая ссылка гугла

Comment: @teran, там нету ответа на вопрос каким образом происходит откат в sql server при использование TRUNCATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DELETE можно откатить и в транзакции и по журналу транзакций(после закрытия транзакции), т.к. для каждой удалённой строки будет запись с её значением.

TRUNCATE можно откатить только в транзакции. Считай, что таблица(а точнее её блоки - экстенты) помечена на удаление, но ещё не удалена физически, пока открыта транзакция.

[Здесь](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-internals-of-sql-truncate-and-sql-delete-statements/) можно почитать подробнее и с примерами